# Is .Net Framework 3.5 installed on this Windows Server 2012 already?

Tags: windows-server-2012, .net, .net-3.5

I am running an installer of a third party app. I am baffled by this message from the installer.

Here is the screenshot of the dialog box:

[image]

However when I check "Add Roles and Features", I can see

[image]

Does it mean the .Net Framework 3.5 is already installed and the installer message is a false alarm?

I come from a linux background so Windows server features are confusing to me at best.  That's why I want to get some feedback if .Net 3.5 is indeed installed or not.

Comment: Well, it looks installed to me, based on that screenshot... but your app seems to think otherwise.  If it were me, first thing I'd do is [try to install the .NET 3.5 framework again](http://www.danielclasson.com/install-net-framework-35-server-2012/), which would serve to repair a damaged/corrupt install as well as install any missing features from a partial install, and if the app still complains after the fact, I'd call up the vendor and insist on an explanation/workaround/refund/etc.

Comment: Yes, you have .NET 3.5 installed. You're trying to install an app whose developers apparently didn't anticipate it would be installed on a server OS and certainly did not test this scenario. If possible, contact the app developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be.  The app (or a component of the app) requires .NET 3.5 and most likely the installer was built such that it installs any dependencies.

You can quickly check which versions of .NET are installed a couple of ways:

1. Look in `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and/or `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64` (for 64-bit).  There will be a folder for each version of the framework that's installed.
2. Have a look at [**this article from MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has several ways.  The easiest from that post is to look in the registry.  For .NET versions 1-4 they will be listed under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP`.  For .NET 4.5 and newer the keys will be under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`.